# What would be the best distributed storage solution for a heavy use web scraper/crawler?

Tags: mongodb, web-scraping, web-crawler, hdfs, couchbase

I'm implementing a web scraper that needs to scrape and store about 15GB+ of HTML files a day. The amount of daily data will likely grow as well.

I intend on storing the scraped data as long as possible, but would also like to store the full HTML file for at least a month for every page.

My first implementation wrote the HTML files directly to disk, but that quickly ran into inode limit problems.

The next thing I tried was using Couchbase 2.0 as a key/value store, but the Couchbase server would start to return Temp_OOM errors after 5-8 hours of web scraping writes. Restarting the Couchbase server is the only route for recovery.

Would MongoDB be a good solution? [This article](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2013/05/13/mongo-bad-for-scraped-data/) makes me worry, but it does sound like their requirements are beyond what I need.

I've also looked a bit into Cassandra and HDFS, but I'm not sure if those solutions are overkill for my problem.

As for querying the data, as long as I can get the specific page data for a url and a date, it will be good.  The data too is mostly write once, read once, and then store for possible reads in the future.

Any advice pertaining to storing such a large amount of HTML files would be helpful.

Comment: Couchbase keeps all the keys in memory (only the keys stay there) the document/values are automatically managed by the internal cache. The Temp_OOM could be managed from your application see http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/handling-temp-oom.html . You should not have to restart your server. But keep in minde that Couchbase will keep the keys in memory so you either have to grow the size of the RAM (new nodes or more ram on each node).

Comment: @Brentley, did Tug Grall's answer help you?

Comment: @TugGrall,Hi, exoplatform.com has been very nicely designed, what framework do you use guys

Comment: It is a little off topic here :) but eXo Platform 4 is using Twitter Boostrap and custom CSS based on the design of the User Experience Team lead by Stevan Lemeur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 50kB per HTML page, 15GB daily gives us 300.000+ pages per day. About 10 million monthly.

MongoDB will definitely work well with this data volume. Concerning its limitations, all depends on **how do you plan to read and analyze the data**. You may take advantage of map/reduce features given that amount of data.

However if your problem size may further scale, you may want to consider other options. It might be worth noting that Google search engine uses BigTable as a storage for HTML data. In that sense, using Cassandra in your use case can be a good fit. Cassandra offers excellen, persistent write/read performance and scales horizontally much beyond your data volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what deployment scenario you did when you used Cassandra to give you those errors .. may be more investigation is required to know what is causing the problem. You need to trace back the errors to know their source, because, as per requirements described above, Cassandra should work fine, and shouldn't stop after 5 hours (unless you have a storage problem).

I suggest that you give MongoDB a try, it is very powerful and optimized to what you need, and shouldn't complain of the requirement you mentioned above.

You can use HDFS, but you don't really need it while MongoDB (or even Cassandra) can do it.